# How to delete a phone number with Twilio PHP SDK?

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I am using Twilio PHP SDK. I have the sid of a phone number. How do I delete it?

The rest API docs shows a delete method but does not have the code for it.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers#list

I've seen some examples on Stack Overflow, but they all seem to be using an older version of the SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired from here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers?code-sample=code-get-an-incomingphonenumber&code-language=php&code-sdk-version=5.x

Example code to `delete()` a Twilio phone number:

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php'; // Loads the library
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$token = "your_auth_token";
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

// Delete a Twilio number based on its sid. If you do not have a sid,
// check out the list resource examples on this page
$number = $client
    ->incomingPhoneNumbers("PN2a0747eba6abf96b7e3c3ff0b4530f6e")
    ->delete();
```

**Warning**: `Once the number is deleted, any code using it, won't work. Be sure you really want to run the code above.`

Comment: what is this PN2a0747eba6abf96b7e3c3ff0b4530f6e ? is it sid of individual number, how can i get sid from twillo number?